# Windows VNC server with command line interface

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, vnc

I am trying to find a VNC server (preferably open source) for Windows platform with CLI. GUI is optional. Most of popular VNC servers say they provide CLI, but in reality all those command line arguments just bring up settings window. Or maybe I am doing something wrong ?

What i need to do is change port and password from command line and start the server.

Thanks

Comment: so did you find that tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to focus on distributing or editing config files & then restarting tbe VNC server to pickup the new config file. Check out the VNC manual for automated or headless installation options.

Comment: Yup, thats the way am doing it right now. But I hoped that there would be a better solution.

Comment: Better in what sense/way?

Answer (score 0):

from Wikipedia:

> In computing, Virtual Network Computing (VNC) is a graphical desktop sharing system that uses the RFB protocol to remotely control another computer. It transmits the keyboard and mouse events from one computer to another, relaying the graphical screen updates back in the other direction, over a network.

So, it's absolutely normal it shows a window interface (GUI). If you only need to change port and password, you could consider to use ssh.

Comment: No, you got me totally wrong. I thought about VNC server's configuration using CLI.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood... RealVNC for linux has CLI. I'm not sure, but I think RealVNC for windows does the same. Maybe these links could help to understand. http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server   http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvncviewer.html

Comment: First of all, its about server not the viewer. Secondly, as I said, on windows those command line arguments just bring up settings window.